# Cannot resolve the symbol raw on Android studio Error

Tags: android-studio

while making the video player on  Android studio i am getting the Error.
Cannot resolve the symbol raw on Android studio Error.  v1.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +  R.raw.introduction); get the Error on this point of the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    VideoView v1;    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              v1 = findViewById(R.id.video1);
              v1.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +  R.raw.introduction);
              MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
              mediaController.setAnchorView(v1);
              v1.setMediaController(mediaController);
              v1.start();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `setVideoPath` use `setVideoURI`

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +  R.raw.introduction));
```

Here is a good resource [Link](https://www.javatips.net/api/android.widget.videoview)

Comment: v1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +  R.raw.introduction)); i tried but still error  Cannot resolve the symbol raw and Uri Android studio Error

Comment: Click on Build -> Clean Project

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        v1 = findViewById(R.id.video1);

        v1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" +  R.raw.introduction));  i tried but still error Cannot resolve the symbol raw and Uri Android studio Error

Comment: Try clean and Rebuild your project.